# CoreData, NSManagedObject fetch or create if not exists

Tags: core-data

I am trying to parse a lot of text files and organize their contents as managed objects. There are a lot of duplicates in the text files, so one of the "collateral" tasks is to get rid of them.

What i am trying to do in this respect is to check whether an entity with the given content exists, and if it doesn't, i create one. However, i have different entities with different attributes and relationships. What i want is a kind of function that would take a number of attributes as an input and return a new NSManagedObject instance, and i wouldn't have to worry if it was inserted into the data store or fetched from it.

Is there one?

I must also say that i am a noob at core data.

---

*Some more detail, if you want:*

I am trying to write a sort of dictionary. I have words (Word{NSString *word, <<-> Rule rule}), rules (Rule{NSString name, <->>Word word, <<->PartOfSpeech partOfSpeech, <<-> Ending endings}), parts of speech (PartOfSpeech{NSString name, <<-> Rule rule}) (i hope the notation is clear).

Two words are equal, if they have the same word property, and "linked" to the same rule. Two rules are the same, if they have the same endings and part of speech.

So far i've written a method that takes NSPredicate, NSManagedObjectContext and NSEntityDescription as an input, and first queries the datastore and returns an entity if it finds one, or creates a new one, inserts it into the datastore and returns it. However, in this case I cannot populate the new entity with the necessary data (within that method), so i have to either pass an NSDictionary with the names of attributes and their values and insert them, or return by reference a flag as to whether i created a new object or returned an old one, so that i could populate it with the data outside.

But it looks kind of ugly. I'm sure there must be something more elegant than that, i just couldn't find it. Please, help me if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basically on the right path.  Core Data is an object graph.  There not a lot of dynamic built in.  There's also no "upsert".  like you surmise, you have to fetch and if it doesn't exist, you insert one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have just started using to handle a fetch-or-create scenario.  I am using a top level managed object which contains a few to-many relationships to subordinate objects.  I have a class that houses a few arrays of data (those are not shown here).  This class is responsible for saving and retrieving to and from core data. When the class is created, I do a fetch-or-create to access my top level NSManagedObject.

```
@implementation MyDataManagerClass

...

@synthesize MyRootDataMO;

- (MyDataManagerClass *) init {

    // Init managed object

   NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

   // Fetch or Create root user data managed object

   NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyRootDataMO" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

   [request setEntity:entityDescription];

   NSError *error = nil;
   NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

   if (result == nil) {
       NSLog(@"fetch result = nil");
        // Handle the error here
   } else {
       if([result count] > 0) {
           NSLog(@"fetch saved MO");
           MyRootDataMO = (MyRootDataMO *)[result objectAtIndex:0];
       } else {
           NSLog(@"create new MO");
           MyRootDataMO = (MyRootDataMO *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyRootDataMO" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
       }

   }

   return self;

}

...
```

Comment: This works great with small data sets, but is very inefficient when scaling up to a larger data set (e.g. a dictionary or thesaurus).

Comment: This is 6 years old code.  I don't remember what it was for, but its written to execute only in its init (note its returning self - not any fetched result). Ostensibly this would be called very few times, perhaps only once at app launch in a singleton initializer, and used solely to give itself access to a single entry point to the managed object tree.  The class could then be scaled out to create a facade to core data.

Comment: Fair enough, an old answer to an old question & more of a technique demo than production code. The OP is asking about large scale data design patterns, for which this solution isn't appropriate. Not that it's wrong at all, just that it's not suited to large data sets. I've used this technique myself on small datasets, for larger data sets (e.g. 10,000 records) I use an NSSet of fetched entity data to determine membership before inserting/updating.