# In Core Data, how to do `if exists update else insert`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

How to do `if exists update else insert` in Core Data?

Do I need to program it step by step or there is actually an API for this?

Comment: This answer's kinda crusty, but sounds like a "no". http://stackoverflow.com/a/5131069/4475605. One approach would be to set a `NSPredicate` and see if you turn up an object. If you do, then you'd update, otherwise create a new `NSManagedObject` into the `managedObjectContext`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is my code in objective c, you can use NSPredicate to check the item already exist,

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Trend_news_table" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"news_id = %@",[user_info objectForKey:@"news_id"]]];
      [request setPredicate:predicate];

      NSError *error = nil;
      NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


      if (results.count > 0)
      {
            NSLog(@"update");
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog(@"Insert");
       }
```

Comment: For multi threaded applications, this method does not guarantee uniqueness of the ID

Comment: @ken for what is your solution?

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev I thought of 2 ways, 1st way is to use core data constraints http://dorianroy.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-implement-unique-constraints-in-core-data-with-ios-9/. Second way is to manage your contexts and always use the same context when adding new data to avoid multi threaded conflicts.